# Does null pointer in a struct occupy more memory than no pointer at all?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, null

I'm trying to make a small text editor and efficient (space/time wise). I also want to save changes to the text; I would save changes and the main text in two lists, both made of nodes like this:

```
struct node{
    int startingLine;
    int endingLine;
    char *line;  
    char *newLine;
};
```

My idea is to use this struct both for the ***text*** list and the ***changes*** list;`line` and `newLine` are to point at char arrays (the lines of text)

when these are ***text*** nodes the `newLine` array is empty or points at null, and when the line gets changed this node is just moved to the ***changes*** list and the `newLine` array gets filled with the new line that replaced the first in the text;

this way I would not have to `free` the node from the ***text*** list and `malloc` another node in the ***changes*** list and also copy all the information; but:

- when I try to set an array to `NULL` i get an error; I wonder why, I thought array names were just pointers?
- also, to use the heap I only know `malloc(sizeof(struct node))`, does it allocate space for the second pointer too even if i don't immediately need it?

So in conclusion I ask if this is a good idea or how to work around it or if it can be polished somehow; maybe immediately after allocating a node I should set `newLine` to `NULL`? A `NULL` pointer occupies no memory at all or still something compared to not putting any pointer in the struct? Because as is said the idea would be to have the ***text*** list made of nodes but with all their "useless" `newLine` pointers hanging there.

Comment: arrays and pointers are completely different

Comment: an array is a block of memory. `malloc(sizeof(struct node)), does it allocate space for the second pointer` what do you *malloc* ... even the answer is very probably *no*. `A NULL pointer occupies no memory ` except when it is saved in memory where it occupies the size of a pointer (typically 32 or 64bits), probably your confuse a pointer and what it points to

Comment: No, the `malloc` allocates memory only for the `struct` and the pointer members it contains - not what they might point to, since `malloc` has no way of knowing that. Those pointer values will be indeterminate until you set them.

Comment: All `char *` values are the same size. Do not confuse the size of the pointer with the size of the thing it points to.

Comment: Array names are "like pointers" in a sense, but they are *constants*. Assigning `array = NULL` is like assigning `5 = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to set an array to NULL i get an error; I wonder why, I thought array names were just pointers?

**No.** An array variable is similar to a pointer, and convertible to a pointer, but it's a different type. See [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/643383) for a more complete answer on this.

> also, to use the heap I only know malloc(sizeof(struct node)), does it allocate space for the second pointer too even if i don't immediately need it?

When you allocate a `node`, the second pointer is part of that structure, so the pointer itself exists. But `malloc()` has no idea what the pointers in your `node` should point to, and it doesn't allocate the memory that `line` and `newLine` point to.

> I ask if this is a good idea or how to work around it or if it can be polished somehow; maybe immediately after allocating a node I should set newLine to NULL?

If the fields in your `node` structure are what you need, then it's fine. Setting `line` and `newLine` to `nil` when you create a new `node` is a good idea so that you won't accidentally dereference a garbage pointer.

> A NULL pointer occupies no memory at all or still something compared to not putting any pointer in the struct?

The pointers themselves are part of the `node` struct, so the take up as much memory as any two pointers. The things that `line` and `newLine` point to use as much memory as they need. If `line` and `newLine` are nil, then they don't point to anything and of course no memory is used. You could have a thousand pointers all pointing to the same block of memory, and the space needed would be still just the size of that block and the space occupied by the pointers themselves. Try to distinguish between a pointer, which is just an address, and the data at that address; they're completely different things.

> So about efficiency, this can be good to avoid creating new nodes and copying in all the data, because just allocating the pointer itself takes very little space i hope?

Yes, a pointer typically takes only 8 bytes on a 64-bit system, so not a lot. But you still have to allocate space for the actual data, so it's not obvious that your approach will be more efficient with respect to space than other methods.

It can be tough to get the hang of pointers at first. The best way to get it is to spend a lot of time with pointers. I'd suggest that you do some exercises to practice, e.g. create a program that breaks some input text into a linked list of words and then sorts the list. To attempt writing a text editor that manipulates blocks of data when your understanding of pointers is shaky is to set yourself up for a world of hurt; time that you spend building your confidence with pointers will pay for itself a hundred times over.

Comment: So about efficiency, this can be good to avoid creating new nodes and copying in all the data, because just allocating the pointer itself takes very little space i hope?

Comment: *`No. An array variable is similar to a pointer, and convertible to a pointer, but it's a different type`* **No** it is wrong: array is continous chunk of memory. It name decays to pointer and its type is actually **the same** as the type of pointer to element of the array.

Comment: @P__J__ If an array *converts* or *decays* to a pointer, what does it decay *from*? Certainly, arrays and pointers are related, but arrays are not "just pointers." I linked to a more comprehensive question in part to avoid the semantic debate that often happens around this issue, so the OP and others can dig in more deeply if they're interested. If the OP had provided the specific error encountered, we might have a good example of the specific difference between arrays and pointers that inspired the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to set an array to NULL i get an error; I wonder why, I thought array names were just pointers?

No. Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be *converted* ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  Otherwise, arrays and pointers are completely different animals.

When you declare an array like

```
int a[10];
```

what you get in memory is

```
+---+
|   | a[0]
+---+
|   | a[1]
+---+
 ...
+---+
|   | a[9]
+---+
```

That's it.  There's no separate pointer object storing the address of the first element.  There's no `a` object separate from the array elements themselves.  It's just a sequence of elements.  During translation, any instance of the expression `a` that's not an operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` will be replaced with the address of `a[0]`.

> also, to use the heap I only know malloc(sizeof(struct node)), does it allocate space for the second pointer too even if i don't immediately need it?

It will allocate space for the `line` and `newLine` pointer members, yes; it won't allocate any additional memory for them to point *to*.  That would have to be done as a separate step, e.g.

```
struct node *n = malloc( sizeof *n );
if ( n )
{
  n->line = malloc( line_length + 1 ); // sizeof (char) is 1 by definition so we don't need a sizeof here, +1 to account for string terminator;
  ...
}
```

This means you'll have to call `free( n->line )` before calling `free( n )`.

> A `NULL` pointer occupies no memory at all or still something compared to not putting any pointer in the struct?

A pointer *object* takes up the same amount of space regardless of whether its value is `NULL` or not.  It's like an `int` takes up the same amount of space whether it's value is `0`, `1`, `65535`, or `2147483647`.

The exact size of a pointer type depends on the platform and the pointer type itself.  C does not require a specific size for pointer types, nor does it require all pointer types to be the same size.  The only requirements are

- `void *` and `char *` have the same size and alignment;
- pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as their unqualified equivalent (i.e., `const int *` and `volatile int *` and `int *` should all have the same size);
- pointers to all `struct` types have the same size and alignment;
- pointers to all `union` types have the same size and alignment;

On most modern, general-purpose platforms like x86 and x86-64, all pointer types will have the same size.  That may not be the case on some embedded or special-purpose architectures, though.